# How do I fix the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: connection refused: no further information:" error for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

[image]

The error only pops up for one server, I've tried reinstalling Minecraft and changing the version, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you allow all the executable files through the firewall, as mentioned in the last post [here](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/2919008-solved-io-netty-channel-abstractchannel)?

Comment: Otherwise maybe give [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/admincraft/comments/80727n/cant_connect_to_server/) a read. You provide little circumstantial information; please update your question with additional details (OS, Minecraft version, when does this problem occur, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

First, next time please include more information about your question, such as the server you are trying to join, or general PC specs - OS etc, or if your game is modded.

To troubleshoot the problem, temporarily disable the firewall. 
Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall (or just type in “Firewall” in the Start Menu search box)

Then, on the left disable the firewall "Turn windows defender firewall on or off" - Try to join the server with this off.

**IMPORTANT: Turn firewall back on after testing - Leaving off can allow malicious programs to gain access to your computer.**

If this solved your problem, you can whitelist (allow) minecraft to bypass the firewall - "Allow and app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall"

You will need to allow
*Java(TM) Platform SE Binary*

If that doesn't work, also try and whitelist the minecraft jar that you play on.

Do this by finding "Allow another app..." then navigating to your minecraft folder. (Browse > Windows Drive > Users > Your user > Appdata > Roaming > .minecraft > versions, then click into the folder of the version you play, and whitelist 1.XX.X.jar (eg: 1.13.2.jar)

If this doesn't work, there are many other reasons that can cause this. It could be server-side - You should contact server administrators, or your ISP could be blocking your traffic.

Feel free to reply/edit